# REGEX, pythonchallenge.com

Tags: python, regex

I need to filter a text like UUUlUUU (i mean Uppercase letter*3 + lowercase letter + Uppercase letter*3). How can i implement that regex?

I know that python alows this:

```
    re.match(\w)
```

i tried like this:

```
    re.match([[A-Z]+[A-Z]+[A-Z]+[a-z]+[[A-Z]+[A-Z]+[A-Z])
```

for finding a single character. (i can add as many \w as i need)

The Question is: is there a way to make a Case Sensitive regex for getting that i what?

p.s. I rather articles for reading instead the single solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you want is

```
'^[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}$'
```

Note that you can use `{}` to specify repetition.

Example

```
import re
re.findall('^[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}$' , 'UUUlUUU')
['UUUlUUU']
```

As far as "articles for reading", the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) is always a good start.

Comment: This may need to be bounded with `\b` or `^$` anchored. Otherwise it matches `AAABBBCCCDDDxZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ` which may not be desired.

Comment: This is incorrect.., the word boundary should be placed outside of the class. `\b[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}\b` It currently matches a backspace character.

Comment: `\b[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}\b` is more appropriate, bounding the entire construct

Answer (score 1):

(https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) has all you need then. Hint: [A-Z]{3} would match exactly 3 uppercase letters

Comment: Actually this article was the solution! thanks a lot.